# Is there any way to edit a local file through a web page without running server software?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I've a web working on a web page that's basically just a big table of links. I use javascript to read from a text file, parse it, and create a table based on that.

I'd like to be able to have a button on the page to add new a row of links and add them to the text file (or another file type if it's better).

I know you can accomplish this with php, node.js, and others, but all the methods I've found require server software to be running. Is there any way around this? For example, is there a way to use javascript to call a python script, or any other way?

The page is just for personal use, so I'd like to avoid running server software just to use it if possible. I know you can set it to download a text file, and you can save it in the same location, but I'd also like to avoid that.

From the research I've done, it doesn't seem possible, but I just thought I'd ask before I give up. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use ajax to post to a python route and tell it what to do from there I suppose.

Comment: I tried doing that, but from what I understand you need apache to handle it.

Comment: Indeed, I was thinking maybe you possibly just didn't want to use a d/b. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only read from files locally in browser with javascript.

This would be a huge security vulnerability if scripts in browsers could write files to your machine.

Comment: That's what I figured. It just seems a bit counterintuitive that a local html file wouldn't be able to edit a local file, but I guess I understand browsers are really designed for accessing servers.